# Rails4.2.5 server is running but no response in browser and curl, Ctrl+c also isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, thin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I launch rails server with`bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000` in Mac OS X ElCapitan.

It works fine and shows me:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Then, I tried access to `http://0.0.0.0:3000` in blowser(Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari), but rails server do not respond me.
Certainly rails do not output log.

curl command like `curl http://0.0.0.0:3000` also do not show response.

[screenshot my trying access to http://0.0.0.0:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGRPT.png)

And, I can not kill proccess with `Ctrl c` or `Ctrl \`or `kill ${process_id}`. So, I have to kill with `-9` option like `kill -9 ${process_id}`.

Previously this issue didn't accrue.

↓ my environment informations

```
% bundle exec rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

% ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]

% bundle exec redis-server -v
Redis server v=3.0.7 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=aa27a151289c9b98
```

### I also tried that:

1. running it on different port with `bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001`. still no respond.
2. creating new rails apps and running them. they are fine(I can access to http://0.0.0.0:3000 with browser).
3. cloning this app from git repo to other directory and trying same things. still no respond.

### Please Your Help!

I am all out of tricks...
Please tell me whatever hints!

thanks.

### references

- [Rails server running but not loading in browser - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160038/rails-server-running-but-not-loading-in-browser)
- [Rails server is running, but cannot connect/ping/telnet to localhost - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343740/rails-server-is-running-but-cannot-connect-ping-telnet-to-localhost)
- [Rails server is running, but cannot connect to localhost:3000 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394238/rails-server-is-running-but-cannot-connect-to-localhost3000)

Comment: Try just `bin/rails server`

Comment: thanks for the response, but same result. rails server is running but no respond.

Comment: Not really sure what happened...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved!!

I solved this issue.
This issue caused by initialize standalone websocket-rails.

This is my old code.

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|
  config.standalone = true
  config.synchronize = true
  config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379', driver: :ruby}
end
```

and, I remove `driver: :ruby`, the issue was fixed.

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|
  config.standalone = true
  config.synchronize = true
  config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379'}
end
```

but now, I am not sure about the causes.
I'll try research.

### references

- [standalone mode FiberError · Issue #231 · websocket-rails/websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/231)
- [Standalone Crash · Issue #239 · websocket-rails/websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/239)